# empApi with Lightning Web Components?

Tags: lightning-web-components, streaming-api, platform-event

I have an LWC in which I want to use EMP API. Docs say that's only currently available in Aura. Do I have to wrap my entire LWC in aura in order to add the EMP API, or can I create a utility aura component and do pub-sub to/from the LWC?

Comment: Adding to all the answers. I have created a library for the lightning web component to use streaming api. It does work in LWC, Aura and mobile app as well.

https://github.com/TheVishnuKumar/lwc-streaming-api

Note: I am using this in the live project for desktop and mobile app both.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Summer 19 is 1 week away, but that won't stop you from preparing it beforehand in your Summer 19 Sandbox or Scratch org.

[lightning:empApi](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:empApi/documentation) does not show LWC button as enabled as its referring to the Spring version of docs.

Also , the [release notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer19/release-notes/rn_platform_event_lwc_empapi.htm) dont tell us about how to use empAPI in LWC. I could not find any public documentation on about how to use it.

A quick way to refer docs of lwc is Summer 19 org is to visit the url

```
https://yourSummer19org.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-emp-api/documentation
```

Sample Example :

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="EmpApi Example" icon-name="custom:custom14">
        <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
            <p>Use the buttons below to subscribe and unsubscribe to a streaming channel!</p>
            <lightning-input label="Channel Name" value={channelName}
                onchange={handleChannelName}></lightning-input>
            <lightning-button variant="success" label="Subscribe" title="Subscribe"
                onclick={handleSubscribe} disabled={isSubscribeDisabled}
                class="slds-m-left_x-small"></lightning-button>
            <lightning-button variant="destructive" label="Unsubscribe" title="Unsubscribe"
                onclick={handleUnsubscribe} disabled={isUnsubscribeDisabled}
                class="slds-m-left_x-small"></lightning-button>
        </div>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

JS:

```
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';
import { subscribe, unsubscribe, onError, setDebugFlag, isEmpEnabled } from 'lightning/empApi';

export default class EmpApiLWC extends LightningElement {
    @track channelName = '/event/Test__e';
    @track isSubscribeDisabled = false;
    @track isUnsubscribeDisabled = !this.isSubscribeDisabled;

    subscription = {};

    // Tracks changes to channelName text field
    handleChannelName(event) {
        this.channelName = event.target.value;
    }

    // Handles subscribe button click
    handleSubscribe() {
        // Callback invoked whenever a new event message is received
        const messageCallback = function(response) {
            console.log('New message received : ', JSON.stringify(response));
            // Response contains the payload of the new message received
        };

        // Invoke subscribe method of empApi. Pass reference to messageCallback
        subscribe(this.channelName, -1, messageCallback).then(response => {
            // Response contains the subscription information on successful subscribe call
            console.log('Successfully subscribed to : ', JSON.stringify(response.channel));
            this.subscription = response;
            this.toggleSubscribeButton(true);
        });
    }

    // Handles unsubscribe button click
    handleUnsubscribe() {
        this.toggleSubscribeButton(false);

        // Invoke unsubscribe method of empApi
        unsubscribe(this.subscription, response => {
            console.log('unsubscribe() response: ', JSON.stringify(response));
            // Response is true for successful unsubscribe
        });
    }

    toggleSubscribeButton(enableSubscribe) {
        this.isSubscribeDisabled = enableSubscribe;
        this.isUnsubscribeDisabled = !enableSubscribe;
    }

    registerErrorListener() {
        // Invoke onError empApi method
        onError(error => {
            console.log('Received error from server: ', JSON.stringify(error));
            // Error contains the server-side error
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

How about option 3: Wait a week.

According to the [release notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer19/release-notes/rn_platform_event_lwc_empapi.htm), EmpApi is currently slated to go live in LWC for Summer 19.

Comment: Yeah, they specifically referenced it in the release webinar yesterday (June 7th)